# Magnitude of reciprocal-lattice vector

Tags: condensed-matter, crystals

I'm reading "A Journey into Reciprocal Space" by Glazer where the metric tensor in reciprocal space is defined as:

> $$M^*=\begin{bmatrix} \textbf{a}^*\cdot\textbf{a}^* &
>  \textbf{a}^*\cdot\textbf{b}^* & \textbf{a}^*\cdot\textbf{c}^* \\
>  \textbf{b}^*\cdot\textbf{a}^* & \textbf{b}^*\cdot\textbf{b}^* &
>  \textbf{b}^*\cdot\textbf{c}^* \\ \textbf{c}^*\cdot\textbf{a}^* &
>  \textbf{c}^*\cdot\textbf{b}^* & \textbf{c}^*\cdot\textbf{c}^*
>  \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} (a^*)^2 & a^*b^*\cos\gamma^* &
>  a^*c^*\cos\beta^* \\ b^*a^*\cos\gamma^* & (b^*)^2 & b^*c^*\cos\alpha^*
>  \\ c^*a^*\cos\beta^* & c^*b^*\cos\alpha^* & (c^*)^2 \end{bmatrix}$$

In the worked example for a monoclinic crystal with $a = 0.6 \text{ nm}$, $b = 0.7\text{ nm}$, $c = 0.8\text{ nm}$ and $β = 110^{\circ}$ the magnitude of the reciprocal-lattice vector of the length denoted by the direction [31-2] is calculated as:

> $$\begin{align*} a^*&=2\pi\frac{1}{a\sin\beta}=11.14\text{ nm}^{-1} \\
>  b^*&=2\pi\frac{1}{b}=8.98\text{ nm}^{-1} \\
>  c^*&=2\pi\frac{1}{c\sin\beta}=8.36\text{ nm}^{-1} \\ \beta^*&=
>  180^{\circ} - \beta = 70^{\circ} \end{align*}$$
> Then
> $$\left((2\pi)^2\begin{bmatrix} 3 & 1 & \overline{2} 
> \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 3.14 & 0 & 0.80 \\ 0 & 2.04 & 0 \\ 0.80 & 0 & 1.77 
> \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 3 \\ 1 \\ \overline{2} 
> \end{bmatrix}\right)^{1/2} = 33.1\text{ nm}^{-1} $$

It's not clear to me how the numerical values were obtained in this matrix; for example, I would say $(a^*)^2=124.19\text{ nm}^{-1}$ rather than $3.14\text{ nm}^{-1}$; is it not?

Comment: Use text instead of images of text whenever possible; see this [meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/320052/why-are-images-of-text-code-and-mathematical-expressions-discouraged).

Answer (score 1):

You have in front the factor term $(2\pi)^2$ , so you must divide all your matrix terms by $({2\pi})^2$,  e.g. for $(a^*)^2, (b^*)^2, (c^*)^2$ by $({2\pi})^2$, just mathematics.

Comment: I don't understand; a* is 11.14. How is it possible that (a*)^2 is 3.14 nm−1 in the matrix, rather than  124.19 nm−1?

Comment: @gryphys You are ignoring the prefactor $(2\pi)^2$. If you take that into account, $(a^*)^2 = \color{red}{(2\pi)^2} \cdot 3.14 \ \mathrm{nm}^{-1} \approx 124 \ \mathrm{nm}^{-1}$.

Comment: @gryphys is it clear now?

Comment: now it's OK, thanks. I did lost the (2π)2 prefactor.